# Porting static html/javascript site to iPad using trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io

Im currently in the process of porting a completely static site using trigger io to convert it to an app. The site comprises of lots of folders in folders with index.html files in them to make the urls nice. The site uses absolute urls to include stylesheets, javascripts, on a tags, and images in every page.

I would like to set a root directory for trigger.io, but I cannot find any way of doing this. Is this even possible?

Cheers,

Rich

Edit:

Example:

```
<script src="/json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<img alt="Bar_hat" class="bar_hat" src="/assets/bar_hat-09efbabebef04dd368425a6b71badfa7.jpg" />
```

The script tag is in all of the files.

The img tag is used in 90% of the files. These are obviously not being found from within the app.

Comment: The entrypoint for any mobile app built with forge is currently always `index.html` in the top level of your app (so that's `index.html` in the `src` folder). Are you asking if it's possible to have the app to start by opening a different file? If so could you give an example of the kind of structure you're using.

Comment: @monk The entry point isn't the problem. Its including the files. See edit

Answer (score 1):

Copy your "assests" directory to the "src" directory and use without a "slash" before assets -

```
<img alt="Bar_hat" class="bar_hat" src="assets/bar_hat-09efbabebef04dd368425a6b71badfa7.jpg" />
```

Also, if you want to access via javascript you must use this pattern:

```
forge.file.getUrl("assets/bar_hat-09efbabebef04dd368425a6b71badfa7.jpg", 
   function(file) {
      //  If using zepto or jquery
      $("#whateverImage").attr("src", file);
   }, 
   function(err) {
     // error
   }
);
```

Edit: getUrl vs getLocal

Comment: Just removing the slash might not be enough to replace absolute paths with relative ones, @DickieBoy will probably want to do e.g. `../foo.png` to reference things from HTML/CSS within a folder. Also, you don't really need `forge.file.getLocal` (though I think you might mean `getUrl` ?) for the example in this answer, you can just use a relative URL for the src attribute of the image: `$('#whateverImage').attr('src', "assets/bar_hat-09efbabebef04dd368425a6b71badfa7.jpg");`;

Comment: Thanks for the reply though I dont think this helps. Might have to do it by hand.